# Display the barcode of each product in a PHP template, using the get post meta key

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to display the product's QR code in a php template in which I have access to product_id, I have the following code but it doesn't work correctly:

```
<?php
echo get_post_meta( $product_id, '_product_qr_code', true );
?>
```

I am using the plugin: **QR Code Woocommerce**, which saves the image of the QR code of each product in the directory: **my-domain/wp-content/uploads/wcqrc-images/1595878862_5631.png** I am attaching an image that shows the meta data product key. [plugin QR Code Woocommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/qr-code-woocommerce/#description)

[image: meta key of product]

[image: QR Code Woocommerce of Product]

Answer (score 1):

I managed to show the QR code of each product in the php template with this code created:

```
<img src="<?php echo WCQRC_QR_IMAGE_URL . get_post_meta( $product_id, '_product_qr_code', true ); ?>">
```